# Export all output lines to CSV in Python, not only the last one

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export

Friends,

I am trying to export the table from a word file to a CSV file, but only the last line is exported.

The code is below as well as the data.

```
import docx
import os
import csv
doc = docx.Document('Decont.docx')
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            data = [cell.text]
            print (data)
with open('Test.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:
    for line in data:
        f.write(line + "\n")
doc.paragraphs[7].text
```

Also, I have an ID in the last line, at paragraph 7. How can I export that as well in the CSV?

This is what i get by printing the data:

```
['1. Cheltuieli aferente spitalizarii (nr. de zile de spitalizare x tarif/zi spitalizare)'] 
['1000'] 
['2. Cheltuieli pentru hrana (alocatia de hrana x nr zile de spitalizare)'] 
['110'] 
['3. Cheltuieli pentru medicamente pe perioada spitalizarii (conform art. 3 din ordinul 1100/2005)'] 
['170,81'] 
['4. Cheltuieli pentru materiale sanitare (conform art. 3 din ordinul 1100/2005)'] 
['34,24'] 
['5. Analize de laborator (conform art. 3 din ordinul 1100/2005)']
['268'] 
['6. Alte investigatii (conform art. 3 din ordinul 1100/2005)'] 
['0'] 
['- Cost medicatie sectia ATI'] 
['0'] 
['- Alte servicii medicale'] 
['0'] 
['TOTAL CHELTUIELI (1+2+3+4+5+6)'] 
['3023,05 Lei'] 
'\nJOHN DOE 233456788991'
```

I would like to get something like this:
233456788991, Cheltuieli aferente spitalizarii, 1000, Cheltuieli pentru hrana, 110, Cheltuieli pentru medicamente pe perioada spitalizarii, 170,81 .....TOTAL CHELTUIELI, 3023,05

Many thanks and much appreciated!

Comment: You are only ever saving one thing in data. try defining data as a list outside of your loops then use data.append() to keep adding data to it so that it holds a list of data

Comment: `with open('Test.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:` Can you change from 'w' to 'a'?

Comment: @ClaudioDavi data will only ever have one item in it which will be the last item of the loop. So opening the file in append mode will still only write one item

Comment: @CrisDoyle You are right, I have not seen that he is overwriting the variable every time. You should submit an answer with this information

Comment: @ChrisDoyle True! That was the issue. Do you have any idea how can I export everything on the same line - each item a cell? Updated code for those of you who are interested: `data = []
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            data.append(cell.text)
            print (data)`